# How do I let everyone edit a repository on GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, edit

How do I let everyone edit a repository on GitHub?
I have a repository on GitHub, but I would like anyone to edit it.
Is there a way to do this?

Other things:
What I mean by **"everyone"** means anyone with an account.

Answer (score 2):

If your repo is a public one, everybody has read access only: see "[Making a private repository public](https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-private-repository-public)"

[image: https://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/repository/repo-publicconfirm.png]

That means anyone can [fork your repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo), and start contributing by [PR (Pull Requests)](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).
You cannot directly grant **write access** to a repo for *everybody*.

When you receive a PR, can can accept it, or (more radical solution), you can add that person as a collaborator: see "[The Pull Request Hack](http://felixge.de/2013/03/11/the-pull-request-hack.html)".

Comment: I wanted everyone to EDIT it. Not just let them read the code.

Comment: @PoniesFiM this doesn't exist. The "Make this repository Public" is only for read-access, not write access. "everyone to EDIT" means fork + pull requests only.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking how to open source it. You do this by going to the repository's main page and clicking on the settings page. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on "Make this Repository Public". You must have ownership of the repository to do this.

Comment: I scrolled down to the bottom of the page, and there wasn't anything that said that.

Comment: Goto settings first.. I can guarantee it is there.